# Photoshop merging layers quality change

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am working on a photoshop paint, and I am using many layers and most of them have effects. When I hit 'merge all', I get a drastic quality change to the image! Here is an example of a part before merging:

[image]

And here is after:

[image]

You can see that most of the shadows are gone, and it overall looks worst..
I have been reading online and figured it something to do with 'vectors' and such, but I want to know if there's a way to fix this issue.

Thank you all for your help and guidance!

Comment: Are you viewing at 100%? Subtle variations *can* appear more or less drastic than they *actually* are when viewing an image and anything other than 100%. There's some "display anti-aliasing" which is used to facilitates faster previewing when an image scaled. You should always view at 100% when merging.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't really replicate this problem, but I can see a difference in your screenshots.  Why are you merging all layers down? Usually you don't need to do that.  Can't you just export as PNG?  Try that, see if it's any better.

Comment: Thank you Billy! I tried exporting but I am getting the same results as merging the layers.. The pictures are at 100% btw.

Comment: Ok, so try this instead: File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy), select PNG as the file format.  If this works, it could be a potential bug with Export As which is a newer feature.

Comment: Looks like this issue has caused problems before. There's a post [here on the Adobe forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/export-as-with-layer-effects/td-p/9580302?page=1) - probably a bug Adobe hasn't fixed yet.